# Pointwise and Uniform convergence in sequences of functions

Tags: analysis, sequence-of-function

I am studying sequences of functions and I got a question:
Is there any example of a sequence of functions that has pointwise convergence in R and doesn't has uniform convergence in any interval of positive length of R ?

Comment: Please specify "range of $\mathbb R$". Do you maybe mean "in each interval of positive length"?

Comment: How about Example 7.4 on "Baby Rudin"?

Comment: @amsmath Yes it is any interval of positive length.. sorry for not clarifying that in my question

Comment: @dnfu Thanks for the example, I need to prove that the formula of the series is integrable in order to prove that it's a correct example

Comment: @dfnu Are you sure you copied the number correctly? That is in the section before uniform convergence.

Comment: @Math1000 the cosine thingy... I thought it could be an interesting starting point to create an example as required by OP, but I may be wrong of course!

Comment: @dfnu probably it's correct but I can't prove it... I need to prove that the cosine thing is integrable because if the sequence is uniformly convergent then it's limit function has to be reimann integrable and we know for sure that the limit function is not reimann integrable

Comment: @Math1000 please read the above comment